# Setting different colors to different bars using array of colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I try to set different colors to different bars using the [Kiran's example](http://bl.ocks.org/kiranml1/6872226).

There is a piece of code I use to do it:

```
var colors =['#0000b4','#0082ca','#0094ff','#0d4bcf','#0066AE','#074285','#00187B','#285964'];

var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
               .range(colors);

colorScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.id; }));

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x",0)
  .attr("y", function(d){return y(d.id);})
  .attr('fill',function(d){ return colorScale(d.id); })
  .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value);})
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

It does not work. And I don't know why. My [working code](https://jsfiddle.net/1nujczwh/2/).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the updated one: 
https://jsfiddle.net/1nujczwh/10/

old:  <del>https://jsfiddle.net/1nujczwh/6/</del>

This is mainly because of your css:

```
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

it overrides the fill attribute.

And since I didn't know how to work with your color scale I left the colorScale(index).

Comment: Thanks! You were right about css and index. I also just changed colorScale.domain and now it works. There is updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/1nujczwh/10/ for someone who is interested.

Comment: @Slava32 Good catch on colorScale.domain. I've changed my fiddle with yours in case someone doesn't see your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Quantize scales accept [numbers as their domain](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize_domain) but the ids you use are strings (`Nord`, `Ost`, etc.). Use an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) instead for an appropriate transformation:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
               .range(colors);
```

And a demo https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/gLw8facy/